# CLOSE_WAIT issue with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, tcp, connection

I have an application with connects to many websites at the same time and download large files over http.

When I check the system with [`TcpView`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fsysinternals%2Fbb897437&rct=j&q=tcpview&ei=_Q92Td-5LInPsgb2m-SBBQ&usg=AFQjCNE9yLgu3xiyf_UMjz24ItlBmV_W7g&cad=rja) there are many connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. My code is something like this:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch
{
    if (response != null)
        response.Close();
}

Stream stream = Response.GetResponseStream();

// read stream until an error happens or we reach end of stream. Then:

if (request != null)
    request.Abort();

if (response != null)
    response.Close();
```

Why I still have many connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the HttpWeb classes you're using, but I can tell you that `CLOSE_WAIT` is the TCP state when the remote side has closed the connection but your application has not.  Hope that helps.